# Как в MVC встроить один view в другой

Tags: php, mvc

У меня есть view главной страницы, меню и авторизации, как мне тогда встроить views авторизации и меню в view главной страницы?

P.S. Спрашиваю отвязанно от конкретного фремворка.
P.S.S. Только начал разбираться с MVC.

Comment: просто вызываете view меню и авторизации внутри view главной страницы. Так как у вес не определено какой из MVC вы используете, вам никакого кода нельзя предоставить. Так как у всех свои вызовы. К примеру у CI это так `$this->load->view('<название view файла>');`

Comment: В конечном итоге все сводится к тому, что в том `view`, где должны быть еще другие `view` будет строка `include ....php`. Которая включает и выполняет указанный файл http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php   либо `ob_start()` и `ob_get_clean()`

Comment: Сейчас смотрю на Symfony 2 (3), как там это делается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно для таких целей используют `partial view`. Если в двух словах, это вид, который специально предназначен для встраивания в другие виды.

Конкретная реализация зависит от используемого фреймворка. У каждой платформы она своя. Однако принцип почти везде один и тот же.