# Как применить один HTML тело 2 и более .php файлу?

Tags: php, mvc

Я делал блог (тестовое задание) используя MVC архитектуру и HTML тело прописал на View (show_main.php здесь и Bootstrap, CSS, JS файлы подключены). Но и на View у меня еще имеется add_article.php (здесь у меня форма т.е добавление статьи) и проблема здесь: отдельно прописать HTML тело я думаю так не делают (и открыть новый файл прописать верхний HTML файл до  потом подключать нужное место, так тоже не делают,верно?), но и сюда тоже надо подключить Bootstrap, CSS файлы. Помогите как вы подключаете так чтобы не запутаться..

Слева вы можете посмотреть мои папки и файлы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за любой ответ...

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут можно посмотреть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479625/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-mvc-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-view-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9?rq=1) вариант.

Я бы сделал View страницы, и в зависимости от запрашиваемой страницы подтягивал нужный View

Comment: т.е прописать в отдельный файл HTML тело до <body>(<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="index.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>) и подключать, я правильно понял?

Comment: Нет дело в том что не облажусь ли я... может это старый метод?